# Java KeyListener's keyReleased not called for left and right arrow keys

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I have a KeyHandler class that implements KeyListener. All keys are working except for the left and right arrow keys which register as pressed but never as released (up and down arrows work, as all other keys do). The key listener is added to a Canvas on a JFrame.

```
public class KeyHandler implements KeyListener {

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Pressed");
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Released");
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

}
```

Is there a reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snippet from java api - Keyevent:

```
Not all keyboards or systems are capable of generating all virtual key codes. No attempt is made in Java to generate these keys artificially.
```

So from Java- side it is still defined behaviour. However from my logic feeling I also cannot give you any difference between up/down and left/right arrow keys.
Just if we follow the API definition. It seems to be system dependent.